# chart.js с vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, диаграммы, chart.js

Всем привет,те,кто знаком с chart.js ,можете ли показать работающий пример круговой диаграммы на vue.js ? Ничего что есть в интернете не работает,или можно что нибудь вывести по такому массиву данных? Буду очень благодарен,если покажете что-то на этом массиве

```
    [ {
  "id" : "1000",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1173166",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Умерший с просрочкой",
  "totalDebt" : 243641.00,
  "userId" : "1000",
  "userFullName" : "admin admin admin",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1000",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1173166/7",
    "make" : "Opel",
    "model" : "Astra",
    "manufactureYear" : 2000,
    "color" : "черный",
    "vin" : "JHLRE48577C415490",
    "licensePlate" : "X001XX73",
    "enginePower" : 90.00,
    "parkingId" : "67",
    "archival" : true,
    "hasImportWarnings" : false,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION_FINISHED"
  },
   {
  "id" : "1001",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1072531",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITH_EXISTING_INSPECTION",
  "evaluationCreatedDate" : "2018-06-04T16:07:25.339",
  "totalDebt" : 131039.00,
  "userId" : "1000",
  "userFullName" : "admin admin admin",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1001",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1072531/7",
    "make" : "ВАЗ (LADA)",
    "model" : "Vesta",
    "manufactureYear" : 2013,
    "color" : "СИНЕ-ЧЕРНЫЙ",
    "vin" : "JKW349786E4781522",
    "licensePlate" : "Е680ТТ98",
    "enginePower" : 999.00,
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : true,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION"
  },
  {
  "id" : "1002",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "915873",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITH_NEW_INSPECTION",
  "evaluationCreatedDate" : "2018-06-01T19:32:53.223",
  "totalDebt" : 323.00,
  "userId" : "1003",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1002",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "915873/1",
    "make" : "Mazda",
    "model" : "Mazda 1979845",
    "manufactureYear" : 2010,
    "color" : "БЕЛЫЙ79879",
    "vin" : "JHLRE48577C415490",
    "licensePlate" : "X001XX73",
    "enginePower" : 100.00,
    "parkingId" : "43",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : false,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION_SENT"
  },
  {
  "id" : "1003",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1236247",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITH_NEW_INSPECTION",
  "evaluationCreatedDate" : "2018-05-17T05:23:55.361",
  "totalDebt" : 413030.00,
  "userId" : "1004",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1003",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1236247/4",
    "make" : "KIA",
    "model" : "Ceed",
    "manufactureYear" : 2014,
    "color" : "Серый",
    "vin" : "TCUTG127EX1585593",
    "licensePlate" : "ыаывавы",
    "enginePower" : 0.00,
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : true,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION_SENT"
  },
  "client" : {
    "clientId" : "1003",
    "clientName" : "Эедвмави Пбьдз Ощнъхбэйъ",
    "clientAddress" : "Тестовый адрес",
    "clientPhoto" : "http://фото_клиента"
  },
  "evaluation" : {
    "carId" : "1003",
    "inspectionId" : null,
    "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITH_NEW_INSPECTION",
    "evaluationCompanyId" : "1",
    "evaluationSum" : null,
    "city" : "asdfasdfasdf",
    "attachmentId" : null,
    "creationComment" : null,
    "finishComment" : null,
    "createdDate" : "2018-05-17T05:23:55.361",
    "sendToEvaluation" : "2018-05-17T07:33:44.447",
    "returnedEvaluation" : null,
    "sendToEvaluationCompany" : "2018-05-17T07:33:44.367",
    "returnedFromEvaluationCompany" : null,
    "finishedEvaluation" : null,
    "clientFullName" : "Эедвмави Пбьдз Ощнъхбэйъ",
    "proxyFullName" : null,
    "proxyPhone" : "234234",
    "proxyNumber" : null,
    "inspectionDateTime" : "2018-05-17T11:32:59",
    "inspectionAddress" : "фывафывафывафывафыва",
    "lawyerFullName" : null,
    "lawyerPhone" : "2342342134",
    "lawyerProxyNumber" : "фывафывафыва"
  },
  "attachments" : [ {
    "id" : "1885",
    "filename" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : "1004",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1238779",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "totalDebt" : 379216.00,
  "userId" : "1005",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1004",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1238779/7",
    "make" : "Fiat",
    "model" : "Punto",
    "manufactureYear" : 2012,
    "color" : "ЧЕРНЫЙ",
    "vin" : "SVJ78783308354104",
    "licensePlate" : "Е911ВВ05",
    "enginePower" : 112.00,
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : true,
    "evaluationStatus" : "UNEVALUATED"
  },
  "client" : {
    "clientId" : "1004",
    "clientName" : "Аоювпъвиэн Трюуьсиж Еооьууьте",
    "clientAddress" : "Тестовый адрес",
    "clientPhoto" : "http://фото_клиента"
  }
}, {
  "id" : "1005",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1254061",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "evaluationType" : "INTERNAL_EVALUATION",
  "evaluationCreatedDate" : "2018-05-16T07:09:19.958",
  "totalDebt" : 213334.00,
  "userId" : "1000",
  "userFullName" : "admin admin admin",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1005",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1254061/8",
    "make" : "ВАЗ",
    "model" : "2190",
    "manufactureYear" : 2014,
    "color" : "ЗОЛОТИСТО-КОРИЧНЕВЫЙ",
    "vin" : "PTP181685L3423924",
    "licensePlate" : "Х275ТУ143",
    "parkingId" : "67",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : false,
    "evaluationStatus" : "VALIDATION"
  },
   {
  "id" : "1007",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1058344",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Field External",
  "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITHOUT_INSPECTION",
  "evaluationCreatedDate" : "2018-05-23T15:05:09.631",
  "totalDebt" : 87825.00,
  "userId" : "1008",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1007",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1058344/4",
    "make" : "ВАЗ",
    "model" : "2190",
    "manufactureYear" : 2012,
    "color" : "БЕЛЫЙ",
    "vin" : "XNE661818Z6957074",
    "licensePlate" : "Т856ТР54BHO",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : true,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION_SENT"
  },
  "client" : {
    "clientId" : "1007",
    "clientName" : "Цъэоме Гизнг Уэнщчхбг",
    "clientAddress" : "Тестовый адрес",
    "clientPhoto" : "http://фото_клиента"
  },
  "evaluation" : {
    "carId" : "1007",
    "inspectionId" : null,
    "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITHOUT_INSPECTION",
    "evaluationCompanyId" : "2",
    "evaluationSum" : null,
    "city" : "гше7858",
    "attachmentId" : null,
    "creationComment" : null,
    "finishComment" : null,
    "createdDate" : "2018-05-23T15:05:09.631",
    "sendToEvaluation" : "2018-06-09T15:38:08.529",
    "returnedEvaluation" : null,
    "sendToEvaluationCompany" : "2018-06-09T15:38:08.502",
    "returnedFromEvaluationCompany" : null,
    "finishedEvaluation" : null,
    "clientFullName" : "Цъэоме Гизнг Уэнщчхбг",
    "proxyFullName" : null,
    "proxyPhone" : "",
    "proxyNumber" : null,
    "inspectionDateTime" : "2018-06-09T18:37:34",
    "inspectionAddress" : "",
    "lawyerFullName" : null,
    "lawyerPhone" : "89657857896",
    "lawyerProxyNumber" : ""
  },
  "attachments" : [ {
    "id" : "1881",
    "filename" : null
  }, {
    "id" : "1882",
    "filename" : "download.pdf"
  }, {
    "id" : "2200",
    "filename" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : "1008",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1309317",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "totalDebt" : 690575.00,
  "userId" : "1009",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1008",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1309317/9",
    "make" : "ГАЗ",
    "model" : "2217",
    "manufactureYear" : 2015,
    "color" : "СЕРЫЙ",
    "vin" : "B34141209V4624924",
    "licensePlate" : "Х123ХХ73",
    "enginePower" : 106.00,
    "withdrawalDate" : "2017-04-05",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : true,
    "evaluationStatus" : "UNEVALUATED"
  },
  "client" : {
    "clientId" : "1008",
    "clientName" : "Эчлаоычт Изэгршч Лшйсзвыисфужч",
    "clientAddress" : "Тестовый адрес",
    "clientPhoto" : "http://фото_клиента"
  }
}, {
  "id" : "1009",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1074174",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "totalDebt" : 255572.00,
  "userId" : "1010",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1009",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1074174/5",
    "make" : "ВАЗ",
    "model" : "2190",
    "manufactureYear" : 2013,
    "color" : "БЕЛЫЙ",
    "vin" : "GGM724162K6433682",
    "licensePlate" : "А861ХВ676",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : true,
    "evaluationStatus" : "UNEVALUATED"
  },
  "client" : {
    "clientId" : "1009",
    "clientName" : "Ыфоо Вычвб Оптпшьну",
    "clientAddress" : "Тестовый адрес",
    "clientPhoto" : "http://фото_клиента"
  }
}, {
  "id" : "1010",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1363042",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITH_EXISTING_INSPECTION",
  "evaluationCreatedDate" : "2018-06-11T09:07:14.34",
  "totalDebt" : 224883.00,
  "userId" : "1011",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1010",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1363042/6",
    "make" : "Opel",
    "model" : "Astra",
    "manufactureYear" : 2008,
    "color" : "СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ",
    "vin" : "R9W4FNC474X563071",
    "licensePlate" : "С249АС13",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : false,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION"
  },
  {
  "id" : "1011",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1224099",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "totalDebt" : 59075.00,
  "userId" : "1012",
  "userFullName" : "",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1011",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1224099/3",
    "make" : "KIA",
    "model" : "Spectra",
    "manufactureYear" : 2008,
    "color" : "ЧЕРНЫЙ ЖЕМЧУГ (ЧЕРНЫЙ)",
    "vin" : "YGRLF813844212011",
    "licensePlate" : "х123х12",
    "enginePower" : 123.00,
    "parkingId" : "43",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : false,
    "evaluationStatus" : "UNEVALUATED"
  },
  {
  "id" : "1012",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "402532",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Legal",
  "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITHOUT_INSPECTION",
  "evaluationCreatedDate" : "2018-05-23T15:08:01.323",
  "totalDebt" : 19702.00,
  "userId" : "1000",
  "userFullName" : "admin admin admin",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1012",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "402532/1",
    "make" : "KIA",
    "model" : "Rio",
    "manufactureYear" : 2003,
    "color" : "Черный",
    "vin" : "B2DZS346886652115",
    "licensePlate" : "",
    "archival" : false,
    "hasImportWarnings" : false,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION_SENT"
  },
  "client" : {
    "clientId" : "1012",
    "clientName" : "Птэччнм Ыфшжюьцгы Эжльсрлвимр",
    "clientAddress" : "Тестовый адрес",
    "clientPhoto" : "http://фото_клиента"
  },
  "evaluation" : {
    "carId" : "1012",
    "inspectionId" : null,
    "evaluationType" : "EXTERNAL_EVALUATION_WITHOUT_INSPECTION",
    "evaluationCompanyId" : "1",
    "evaluationSum" : null,
    "city" : ".78979879",
    "attachmentId" : null,
    "creationComment" : null,
    "finishComment" : null,
    "createdDate" : "2018-05-23T15:08:01.323",
    "sendToEvaluation" : "2018-05-23T15:39:20.218",
    "returnedEvaluation" : null,
    "sendToEvaluationCompany" : "2018-05-23T15:39:20.203",
    "returnedFromEvaluationCompany" : null,
    "finishedEvaluation" : null,
    "clientFullName" : "Птэччнм Ыфшжюьцгы Эжльсрлвимр",
    "proxyFullName" : null,
    "proxyPhone" : "0.78979879",
    "proxyNumber" : null,
    "inspectionDateTime" : "2018-05-23T18:38:55",
    "inspectionAddress" : ".78979879",
    "lawyerFullName" : null,
    "lawyerPhone" : "0.78979879",
    "lawyerProxyNumber" : ".78979879"
  },
  "attachments" : [ {
    "id" : "2006",
    "filename" : null
  } ]
```

Comment: где здесь массив ?))

Comment: исправил и добавил)

Comment: @Jarvis могу только посоветовать https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs

Comment: @Jarvis, вопрос заключается в том - что именно вы хотите визуализировать? у вас все свойства - строковые литералы

Comment: например по totalDebt